# Variable Returns False, but if statement doesn't acknowkedge it

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an if statement that is supposed to execute code if a variable returns false, but even though I have checked and made sure the variable returns false, the code does not execute. Here is the code:

SOLUTION: i seem to have accidentally misplaced the if statement, and have moved it and fixed the program. thank you everyone who has helped me fix my problem

```js
function letterCheck() {
            var wordToGuess = puzzle;
            var letterToGuess = guess;
            console.log(letterToGuess);
            matched = false;
            for (x = 0; x < wordToGuess.length; x++) {
                if (letterToGuess === wordToGuess[x]) {
                        console.log('Your guess was correct!');
                        console.log('You have', 6 - parts, 'incorrect guesses remaining');
                        blanks[x] = letterToGuess;
                        console.log(blanks);
                        var fillBlank = '';
                        for (y = 0; y < blanks.length; y++) {
                                fillBlank += blanks[y];
                        }
                        document.getElementById('puzzle').innerHTML = fillBlank;
                        matched = true
                        win++
                        if (win === puzzle.length) {
                            setTimeout(() => alert("You win!"), 100)
                        }
                        break;
         
                }

        }
    }


//this is the if statement that is not working
if (this.matched === false) {
        console.log("Your guess was incorrect!");
        parts++;
        graphics[parts - 1]();
        console.log('You have', 6 - parts, 'incorrect guesses remaining');
}
```

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is, at least based on this code sample.

Comment: are you using that if condition inside any function ?

Comment: Where exactly is the `if` statement placed and when it is run, and how exactly have you checked the value of `this.matched`? What is `this`supposed to be, `window`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"matched" and "this.matched" are 2 different variables. "matched" is global, "this. matched" is local to the function.

To fix: Use either of "matched" or "this.matched" everywhere - don't mix and match.

Comment: To which function `this.matched` is local? The expression using `this.matched` is in the global scope in the provided snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this solution still did not work. there's probably an error I'm not seeing and will continue to work at it.

Comment: Where are you calling letterCheck() ? It all depends on how your program is organized. You would have to put a working snippet for help. Currently your snippet does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic questions need to be asked first. What programming language are you using?

I will assume that you are using JavaScript, because that is the only language that comes to mind that has a `===` operator. The identity operator `===` behaves identically to the equality operator `==` except no type conversion is done. The identity operator requires that all types must be the same types to be considered equal.

Therefore, the `==` equality operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions, while the `===` identity operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type, the identity operator will simply return false.

Both operators execute at approximately the same speed, so if I were you, I would switch to the equality operator and try again. Let me know what you get!

Reference: http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm

Comment: Missed that, obviously. I generally look for that info in the title when deciding what to respond to.

Comment: The tagging system is especially for delivering that information, including the language in the title is not preferred at SO. Just click a tag, and find a new way to find interesting questions ...

Comment: Obviously, I'm not on here often enough to remember that. Only on slow days lol

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this solution still did not work. there's probably an error I'm not seeing and will continue to work at it.